# What is the term to use when logging an event where a user downloads or prints PHI?

Tags: hipaa

My application logs accesses to PHI. I need to add a log item for things like downloading and printing.

Is there a general term that I can use to describe these events? I'm thinking something like "export" or "externalize".

I want to represent that the user took an action which yielded a file or hard-copy of PHI which my software can no longer track.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RFC 3881](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3881.txt) details a format for capturing security audits in healthcare applications.  It is the starting point for audit logs in the DICOM standard and IHE.

In any case, it discusses Export and Import events specifically in the case of printing and creating media. I would stick with the term Export.

Answer (score 2):

The HIPAA term for it is "disclosure"

Comment: Looking at RFC 3881 I see export and disclosure. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Export usually makes me think of just a download something like 'Output' is pretty generic:

```
02/09/12 12:00:00 Output - User - action detail
```